# Does "right justified" mean the same thing as "right flush"?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, justification

This picture helps considerably, but does not use the terms "right justified" or "left justified" that I often see on this forum. Do these mean, respectively, the same thing as "flush right" and "flush left"?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct: "ragged-right" and "flush-left" are the same, and "ragged-left" and "flush-right" are the same. (Often, these terms are written without hyphens.) In my opinion, the terms "left-justified" and "right-justified" can cause confusion if readers aren't also familiar with the term "fully-justified".

In LaTeX, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` are set up as commands, whereas `flushright` and `flushleft` (note the absence of backslash characters) are set up as environments.

If `\raggedright` or `\raggedleft` are in effect -- or, equivalently, if one is in a `flushleft` or `flushright` environment -- hyphenation is generally disabled. If you do want to permit hyphenation, you should load the [ragged2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package and use its commands `\RaggedRight` and `\RaggedLeft` instead of the LaTeX kernel commands `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`.

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\raggedleft
Hello

World
\par
\endgroup

\begin{flushright}
Hello

World
\end{flushright}

Hello, World.
\end{document}
```